How do I keep the Project Tool Window from closing when I switch editor tabs in IntelliJ?
How do I keep the Project Tool Window from closing when I switch editor tabs?
It seems to close on some editor tabs/files and not others.
I would like the Project Tool Window to stay open all of the time.
